# Using Angular 2 Components inside Material <md-tab-group>

Tags: javascript, angular, components, material-design, angular-material

I'm starting an Angular 2/Material Design project and have run into a problem when trying to use components with `<md-tab-group>`. I've seen the general structure examples like the following:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Gallery"> 
   //gallery content here
  </md-tab>
 <md-tab label="Settings"> 
   //setting content here
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

However, I'd like to modularize the functionality of each tab and it's contents into separate Angular 2 components like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<md-tab-group>
  <app-gallery></app-gallery>
  <app-settings></app-settings>
</md-tab-group>
```

The structure I have at the moment follows the basic Angular 2 component conventions, for example:

**gallery.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I then use the `<md-tab>` element inside each component's template like so.

```
<md-tab label="gallery">
    <p>Gallery here...</p>
</md-tab>
```

Finally, I've made sure everything is imported and declared properly.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './core/app.component';
import 'hammerjs';
import { GalleryComponent } from './gallery/gallery.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GalleryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is this possible? At the moment I'm suspecting maybe it's not possible to extract the `<md-tab>` element from the `<md-tab-group>`. To me it seems cumbersome to include all tabs and their contents in one single html file, not to mention defeating the purpose of Components. If it is possible to do I'd be grateful for any guidance on how to set it up correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Also I cant see any selector defined for your `app-settings` in `app.component.html`.

Comment: I just used one component, `<app-gallery>`, as an example and for brevity. `<app-settings>` exists and is constructed exactly the same. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The components you put into tabs should not depend on the tabs. Therefore, they should not be wrapped in `md-tab` in their templates. Material tabs are designed as a container you can put anywhere with almost any content you desire. It serves the purpose of single responsibility, not defeats it.

**EDIT**
As requested, a sample of how it might look like. I assume there are three components: GaleryComponent (gallery with tabs), PicturesGridComponent (displays a grid of pictures) and PictureComponent (displays formatted picture). Templates are simplified to show the structure of nesting components.

GaleryComponent template:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="cats">
    <app-pictures-grid [pictures]="catPictures"></app-pictures-grid>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="dogs">
    <app-pictures-grid [pictures]="dogPictures"></app-pictures-grid>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

PictureComponent template:

```
<app-picture *ngFor="let picture of pictures" [picture]=picture>
```

If tabs are an enumerable object, you can always try to create them with ngFor (I did not test it).

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code based on my question's app structure and the `<app-gallery>` component example. I got it working but think your answer may not be completely clear to some others that may run into this problem. Cheers!